# ASP.NET MVC Large file upload to REST API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, httpclient

I have an ASP.Net  MVC application that upload files to storage nodes via REST API. I do not have control over the storage apart from using the API's to upload and download. This is what i typically do on an upload file.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task UploadFile()
    {
        //Get stream from file to upload
        using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Request.Files[0].FileName))
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api-upload.abc.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

            var res = await client.PutAsync("/streaming/" + Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName),
                new StreamContent(fileStream));

            ViewBag.Result = res.Result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This works for files of smaller size. I would like to upload files > 2GB, in that case this app I was planning for breaking the file in chunks.

```
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                //tempStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            }
```

This approach again I need to have a temporary stream to merge, because I need to push the file to a REST API. This also will run into Out Of Memory(or there is not enough space on the disk) error. I have been doing some reading on this on several posts, there some ways with jquery controls that too led to same OOM, because of the chunk merging in the server side code. I'm looking for solution with .NET to stream files directly to REST API in a web application, if available.

I have set maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength to max values.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2097152"/>

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Below is the response on uploading large files.

```
            HTTP / 1.1 500 Internal Server Error
            Cache - Control: private
            Content-Length: 9918
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
            Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
            X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
            X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: can you show the web.config entries for maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength

Comment: @GregH Updated the question with webconfig